# Java Non-static array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to find dynamic array using in java. I know I can use **ArrayList** or **List** but i cant use them now, I really made an effort about finding this, but i couldn't find how to use non static(dynamic) array without **Collections**, thanks

Comment: Why do you need to create a dynamic array? Why can't you use collections? What are you trying to do? How are you failing?

Comment: It is my project and I cope with this about 6 days and still i cant find how to create dynamic array without collections, just collections are prohibited

Comment: If you can't use collections, you will have to either create an array each time you add something, like suggested below, or else, create a very large array the first time and keep adding stuff to it. If I where you I would go with the first choice.

Comment: you just see the source code of arraylist and understand

Answer (score 6):

Arrays have fixed length in Java. There's no way around that.

If you want to add an `N`:th element to an array, `arr` with length `N-1` then you'll have to

1. Create a new array.
2. Copy over the content of the old array to the new array
3. Replace all references to the old array with references to the new on.

In code these steps correspond to

```
int[] newArr = new int[N];
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, newArr, 0, arr.length);
arr = newArr;
```

or, slightly shorter by using `Arrays.copyOf` from Java 6:

```
int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, N);
arr = newArr;
```

Comment: It provides dynamic array using?

Comment: No. It *replaces* the old array with a new array which is longer. There's no such thing as a dynamic array in Java. If you are prevented to use the Collections API, then I suggest you write your own list class that provides this functionality.

Comment: "own list class" can you brief this? I really new in java also

Comment: Here are few examples [link1](http://www.journaldev.com/110/how-to-implement-arraylist-with-array-in-java), [link2](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/52276).

Comment: sorry but in this examples they have used static variable but i cant use them

Comment: If it is the 'static' keyword you want to avoid, you can remove it the examples in the above links. Won't change how the program works. Give it a try, and come back and post a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: I have no environment about IT thats why i have to cope with them alone, and thats why i had to ask this in here, I just want to learn about this and develoop myself

Answer (score 1):

Normal arrays in Java are not dynamic, so when you want to change the size of the array, you need to create a new one and copy the content of the previous one into it.

You can do that using [`Arrays#copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) method to create and copy it in a simple way:

```
int[] myNewIntArray = Arrays.copyOf(oldIntArray, newArraySize);
```

Comment: No, this is only a convenient way to create new array and copy the content in one line.

Comment: i have to create and delete elements from non-fixed sized array thats why i need like a dynamic array

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own dynamic array. Create an array of size 1 (or n if an initial size is provided), then double the size and copy existing elements once it reaches the capacity.

And this is going to have an amortized cost of 3 per operation, 3n for n elements, meaning you can maintain that in o(n) time.

A very simple naive implementation (for int array) would be:

```
class DynamicIntArray
{
    private int capacity;
    private int[] array;
    private int size = 0;

    public DynamicIntArray()
    {
        this(1);
    }

    public DynamicIntArray(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        array = new int[this.capacity];
    }

    public void add(int a)
    {
        if (size == capacity)
            resize();
        array[size] = a;
        size++;
    }

    private void resize()
    {
        capacity *= 2;
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, capacity);
    }

    // Implement the rest
}
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
DynamicIntArray dynamicArray = new DynamicIntArray();
dynamicArray.add(1);
dynamicArray.add(2);
dynamicArray.add(3);
```

If you change it to use generics you can use it for anything, not just integers.

Comment: how can use this ? It needs Static variable?

Comment: why did you use resize with (*2)? i cant understand thats why i am asking sorry

Comment: This is how I'm told in the algorithms class ;-) I think Java's ArrayList also does it. The key idea is to do less frequent copying when the array gets really big. You wouldn't mind copying on 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. but you don't want this happening once you have 1000000 items every time you chuck in 10 more elements.

Comment: yes it is logical:-) so when i add new item to array it do this in same time?

Comment: class BookArrayBean
{
    private int capacity;
    private Book[] array;
    private int size = 0;

    public BookArrayBean()
    {
        this(1);
    }

    public BookArrayBean(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        array = new Book[this.capacity];
    }

    public void add(Book a)
    {
        if (size == capacity)
            resize();
        array[size] = a;
        size++;
    }

    private void resize()
    {
        capacity *= 2;
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, capacity);
    }

    // Implement the rest
}

Comment: i found Book type which includes book info. so can i use this array for this?

Comment: This is good, although you can use Generics if you want to use this for other types as well.

Comment: so how can i delete item from this array? and should i resize this array after deleting item?

Comment: Arrays don't have a good support for deletion in the middle. You need to move all the elements once something is deleted in the middle. You should consider using linked lists if you have many deletions. No resize for deletions.

Comment: actually i have a library system and i created Type BOOK and i have to create new book to system or delete from this system thats why i asked;)

Comment: also why you write 
    public DynamicIntArray()
    {
        this(1);
    } it is only for ints? or can i use this(1) for my Book attribute?

Comment: 1 is the default capacity, and has nothing to do with int.

Comment: also i wrote this code and tried but when i print this array to console i face with like exp2.model.Book@ca0b6 why i cant see my Book clearly?

Comment: @ca0b6 why console gives me like this? i think it looks like an adress but i cant reach item?

Comment: That's because you haven't overridden toString() method in Book.

Comment: so just using toString fixes this?

Comment: and can you give how can use toString method in Book class ?

Comment: @engineer If you have additional questions, ask them as questions. It's really not polite to keep asking someone to revise their answer as you work through your problem. Otherwise, please move extended discussion to [chat].

Comment: sorry about this, if ı hurted anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You just allocate them like this:

```
int[] array = new int[17];
```

Comment: another terminology is used within c, this hinted me that OP came from a c background and just wanted to allocate an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Collection until the type array is needed and then get your array by using Collection.toArray() function.

Answer (score 0):

You could mimick dynamic behaviour by creating a new array when it is close to getting full e.g., create a new array with twice the length of the original array, and copy all the elements over.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would get even better answers if you explain what you are trying to do and why you can't/won't user Collections. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?